# PANDAS: Count number of rows by ID above threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently having trouble determining a way to count the number of records, by a column containing an identifier, where a number is above a threshold, on a per day basis.

Ie: For each day, in Location 1, in how many rows/records was 'Temp' above the value 20?
Where a day contains no values that are above 20, the result should be 0.
The result should be in a new dataframe.

DateTime is present as a Pandas datetime64[ns] object.

I have about 10 million rows to go through, and anticipate this to be a regular query - so wouldn't mind sticking with pandas vectorised approaches (ie lambda might not be a good choice).

Sample Data: [here as a csv](https://gist.github.com/sxwebster/230195a348fb5f6a245378a51e754bb0).

```
Name: df
+----------+-----------------+------+
| Location |    DateTime     | Temp |
+----------+-----------------+------+
|        0 | 3/03/2021 7:00  |    5 |
|        0 | 3/03/2021 8:00  |   10 |
|        0 | 3/03/2021 9:00  |   15 |
|        0 | 3/03/2021 10:00 |   10 |
|        0 | 3/03/2021 11:00 |   15 |
|        0 | 3/03/2021 12:00 |   20 |
|        0 | 3/03/2021 13:00 |   20 |
|        0 | 4/03/2021 8:00  |   25 |
|        0 | 4/03/2021 10:00 |   15 |
|        0 | 4/03/2021 12:00 |   10 |
|        0 | 4/03/2021 13:00 |   10 |
|        0 | 4/03/2021 15:00 |    5 |
|        0 | 4/03/2021 20:00 |    5 |
|        1 | 4/03/2021 7:00  |    5 |
|        1 | 4/03/2021 8:00  |    5 |
|        1 | 4/03/2021 9:00  |   10 |
|        1 | 4/03/2021 10:00 |   15 |
|        1 | 4/03/2021 12:00 |   15 |
|        1 | 4/03/2021 14:00 |   10 |
|        1 | 5/03/2021 15:00 |   30 |
|        1 | 5/03/2021 17:00 |   30 |
|        1 | 5/03/2021 18:00 |   20 |
|        1 | 5/03/2021 20:00 |   15 |
|        1 | 5/03/2021 21:00 |    5 |
|        1 | 5/03/2021 23:00 |    5 |
+----------+-----------------+------+
```

Sample Output

```
Name: df2
+----------+-----------+-------+
| Location |   Date    | Count |
+----------+-----------+-------+
|        0 | 3/03/2021 |     2 |
|        0 | 4/03/2021 |     1 |
|        1 | 4/03/2021 |     0 |
|        1 | 5/03/2021 |     3 |
+----------+-----------+-------+
```

Thoughts:
If I use .loc() I'm potentially going to lose those Locations with no Temp above 20.

If I use .resample() I don't believe I can set a threshold where Temps are above 20, but I can resample by day using the Location column.

Currently I'm using this, but am having issues with the results, with extraordinary counts occuring.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(r'c:\Temp\GistExample.csv') #My dataframe is constructed differently. This may need to be cast to DateTime

#Find number of hours per day above 20
df2 = df1[['Location', 'DateTime', 'Temp']].copy()
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DateTime']).dt.date
df2['IsItAbove20'] = 0
df2.loc[(df2['Temp'] >= 20), 'IsItabove20'] = 1

TimeAbove = df2.groupby(['Location', 'Date'])['Temp'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: I believe your `groupby.sum` should be on the column `IsItAbove20` and not `Temp` if you want the count actually

Comment: You're probably right. D'oh